# MediaStore - delete file after making folder hidden

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm operating on the `MediaStore` directly and add/remove files from there whenever my app add/removes files. I want fast and instant `MediaStore` updates and the support of batch operations, that's why I do that. Here's an example of an add operation:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
File f = new File(path);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, dateModified / 1000L);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, ExtensionUtil.getMimeType(fileName));
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION, rotation);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
if (latitude != null || longitude != null)
{
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE, latitude);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE, longitude);
}
ContentProviderOperation operation = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(uri)
            .withValues(values)
            .build()
```

Here's an delete operation:

```
String columnData = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
ContentProviderOperation operation = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(uri)
            .withSelection(columnData + "=?", new String[]{path})
            .build();
```

With this sort of operations I'm able to handle all cases and execute them in batches as I desire.

**Problem**

Hide a folder. If I hide a folder, I create a .nomedia file in it, afterwards I want to remove the entries of all medias in it from the `MediaStore`, BUT KEEP the files on the storage of course. Any ideas how I could create operations that do not delete the file as well?

I don't want to use the `MediaScanner`, I'm optimising speed and I need the operations so that I can call a lot of them in a batch if possible...

Comment: Just switch your device off/on.

Comment: `if (latitude != null || longitude != null)`. If only one is null you are still putting them both.

Comment: I'm writing software for users.. Turning phone off is no solution... The latidute thing is intended, I don't want to use data that is already present. My code will take care of everything where needed, even invalid meta data...

Comment: You can direct the MediaScanner to only your directory. Why would that be not fast enough?

Comment: It is MUCH slower than operating on the media store. If you want to move a folder with 1000s of files, operations + batch works nearly instantly, the MediaScanner is way slower... As I said, I want to get the most out of it in the sense of speed. And I need to block the worker thread until the scanner has finished, as I need data from the result... it's working, but example with moving files show me significant speed differences...